# Running Tshark with a python script

Tags: python, tshark

I'm trying to get tshark running through a python script and get a traceback [and I'm using ptyhon 3.9]

This is the python script which I'm using:

```
import subprocess
from pythonosc import osc_message_builder, udp_client # python 3.3.x+

osc = udp_client.UDPClient('localhost', 8000)
popen = subprocess.Popen(['tshark', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for traffic in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ''):
    traffic = traffic.decode('utf-8').strip()
    #print(traffic)
    msg = osc_message_builder.OscMessageBuilder(address='/tsharky')
    msg.add_arg(traffic, 's')
    msg = msg.build()
    osc.send(msg)
```

This is the traceback that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/trem/Downloads/tsharky-master/tsharky.py", line 18, in <module>
    popen = subprocess.Popen(['tshark', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tshark'
```

Where should this directory be and how can I get this code running?

Answer (score 1):

#### Error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tshark'

This is the important error to look at. It means that 'tshark' has not been found by python, meaning one of a couple of things:

1. tshark is not installed
2. tshark is installed, but it's not in [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))
3. tshark is installed, but python can't find it

It looks like your OS is macOS based on the `/Library...` error.

#### 1. Install tshark

If you haven't installed tshark, you can install it with `brew install --cask wireshark` or by downloading the installer from [wireshark.org](https://wireshark.org). Then, when you use `tshark` in scripts (and it's on the PATH), you won't get a file-not-found error.

#### 2. Add tshark to PATH

If you run `which tshark` on your terminal and get no response, tshark is not on your PATH. To add it, add this to your `~/.profile` file (`~/.zprofile` if using zsh):

```
export PATH=/path/to/tshark:$PATH
```

You can check this in python with

```py
import os
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

which should print out the current PATH. Keep in mind that you may need to restart your shell/terminal for your profile changes to take effect.

#### 3. Use the tshark path in place of 'tshark' in Popen

You can check where tshark is installed by running `which tshark`. If `which tshark` returns a value, you can use that filepath in place of `'tshark'` in Popen in your script.

On my Macbook, it's located at `/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/tshark`, but it may well be in a different place on your system.